# Error creating PDF in NodeJS using html-pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation

I'm using below code to generate PDF using html-pdf library the code is working and generate and save the pdf on my local system but when i go with server its giving error. Node library is :- `html-pdf`

```
pdf.create(html).toFile(config.media_image+`invoices/invoice-${params._id}.pdf`,
function(err, res){console.log(res.filename);}});
```

But it's not working on the server and working fine in local system.below the error is:-

```
events.js:167
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event        
    Error: write EPIPE
        at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:792:14)
    Emitted 'error' event at:
        at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
        at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:456:5)
        at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:40:7)
        at Socket._destroy (net.js:617:3)
        at Socket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:32:8)
        at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:794:10)
```

Please let me know the issue....

Comment: make sure you have libfontconfig installed: `apt-get install -y libfontconfig`. Also, add path to phantomjs in options `phantomPath: './node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs',` You will need phantomjs in node modules: `npm install phantomjs-prebuilt`

Comment: @AbhasTandon i'm using html-pdf not phantomjs...

Comment: https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/385

Comment: i had the same issue and 'libfontconfig' was missing...worked like a charm after installing libfontconfig. Thanks @AbhasTandon